# tmux open a new window but is not the same as the original one

Tags: tmux

Hi I am now using tmux and something bothers me now.

I remember that when `Ctrl + B C` will open up a new window and this window will remain the original window's status, which means that if i ssh login to a remote server, and then I call `Ctrl + B C`, and the new window will also ssh login to the remote server, cause they are like in the same session or what.

but now it's now work this way, the new window is in my own host and has pwd with $HOME, just like open a new tab in iTerm, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the expected default behaviour of TMUX,
from the documantation

> If shell-command is not specified, the value of the default-command option is used

basically you need to bind a key and set a command to run when starting a new window
however since tmux is running on your host it will not know what is running in the window you have open.

Comment: I used to use tmux ( not for long ) at work, I remember that I have to ssh just once every day, then I will have all my window got the ssh connection.

Comment: i understood the question however it is not the default behavior, and i suspect one of two options, 
1. you had a custom tmux commmand that actually connected before hand
or 
2. you had a tmux.conf file that specified special cases for opening a new window 
in any case tmux cannot connect alone as it doesn't actually know what is inside your terminal window

Answer (score 1):

You ssh into the remote server, execute tmux as command to start a new tmux session. Then, when you want to leave the tmux session you use the detach command, after which you can safely close the ssh session without killing off whatever is still running in the tmux session. When you return you use `tmux attach` to attach to the still running tmux session and resume work where you left off.

Comment: I have to execute tmux in my local host before I ssh into the remote server. And what I'm trying to do is when I create a new window in Tmux, I want to keep the ssh connection in the new window.